# Text Field not being updated in NSNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I am doing a simple tutorial on `NSNotification` and facing some problems in executing it properly. When I click the button on the First View, the text field in the second view does not get update. When i debug by placing a `NSLog` in the `receiveNotification`, no response. Not sure why the `receiveNotification` is not being called.

The code looks like this:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

}
-(IBAction)one:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)two:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)secondview:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)one:(id)sender{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test1" object:self];
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
-(IBAction)two:(id)sender{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test2" object:self];
     NSLog(@"Hello");
}
-(IBAction)secondview:(id)sender{
    SecondViewController *secondview = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:secondview animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITextField *counterOneText;
    IBOutlet UITextField *counterTwoText;
    int counterOne;
    int counterTwo;
}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;
@end

SecondViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        counterOne = 0;
        counterTwo = 0;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification) name:@"Test1" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification) name:@"Test2" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Test1"])  {
        counterOne++;
        counterOneText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counterOne];
        NSLog(@"%@",counterOneText.text);
        NSLog(@"Hello");
    }else
    {
        counterTwo++;
        counterTwoText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counterTwo];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receiveNotification` is not getting called because your `SecondViewController` was never instantiated. It cannot possible be called when the object doesn't exist. If you pressed `secondView`, `back`, then click `one` or `two`, then the receiveNotification will trigger.

**EDIT:**
I copied and pasted your code to test it out and I got most of what you want it to do. You will still have to press `secondview` first, then `back`.

In ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController (){
    SecondViewController *secondview;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self){
        secondview = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)one:(id)sender{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test1" object:self];
}
-(IBAction)two:(id)sender{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test2" object:self];
}
-(IBAction)secondview:(id)sender{
    [self presentViewController:secondview animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    int counterOne;
    int counterTwo;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *counterOneText;

@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *counterTwoText;


-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

In SecondViewController.m

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

```
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize counterOneText, counterTwoText;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        counterOne = 0;
        counterTwo = 0;

        self.counterOneText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 150, 30)];
        self.counterOneText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.counterOneText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:counterOne]];

        self.counterTwoText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 30)];
        self.counterTwoText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.counterTwoText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:counterTwo]];

        //self.counterOneText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counterOne];
        //self.counterTwoText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counterTwo];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"Test1" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"Test2" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Test1"])  {
        counterOne++;
        NSLog(@"counterOne: %d", counterOne);
        counterOneText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:counterOne]];

        NSLog(@"counterOneText.text: %@",counterOneText.text);
        NSLog(@"Test1");
    }else
    {
        counterTwo++;
        NSLog(@"counterTwo: %d", counterTwo);
        counterTwoText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:counterTwo]];

        NSLog(@"counterTwoText.text: %@",counterTwoText.text);
        NSLog(@"Test2");


    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.counterOneText];
    [self.view addSubview:self.counterTwoText];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. I got it to work. I even got the numbers updating. Hold on I'm editing my answer.

Comment: firstly thanks for taking your time to solve the error. Secondly, when you click the first time, the value of the text in counterone is (null)? shouldn't it be zero?

Comment: Yes, it should be 0. I said in my edit "I got most of what you want it to do". I am myself not sure why it's (null) for now. If I were to guess, it is because IBOutlet UITextFields are created after the view is loaded. If the UITextFields were made programmically instead of using IBOutlet, it might show zero instead of (null). Again, that is just a guess...

Comment: I just created the UITextFields programmically, and it works now. I'll upload it now.

Answer (score 0):

Not `@selector(receiveNotification)`, should be `@selector(receiveNotification:)`

Comment: How can you your two buttons which will call one: and two: can be pressed? I supposed that SecondViewController will presented in full screen, and you may not press those buttons in FirstViewController

Comment: Ok, you have two methods in ViewController, one: and two:. When will you call those methods? When calling those methods, is secondview allocated and presented?

Comment: ok..how do you pass the method's one and two to secondview? how do you solve this problem?